# Questions relating to homework?

Tags: discussion, flags

It seems a decent amount of questions are directly related to homework or job interview problems.  (E.g. almost anything having to do with the Fibonacci sequence.)  Is there a policy on these?  Is there a specific flag that could be applied to them?  Is this an issue that concerns the SE community?  While I enjoy being helpful, I get a weird feeling when answering a question that I suspect will be turned in as school work.

Comment: Related: ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a specific flag that could be applied to them?

No, there isn't.

> Is this an issue that concerns the SE community?

Not really. So long as the questions are high quality and not duplicates, all is well. If it isn't, the existing flag types are usually suitable.

The general guidance on answering these has been in the past (and probably still is) - give enough information for the OP to get going but don't give them the full answer (i.e. teach them to fish, don't give them a fish).